# Let'sEncryptの更新エラーについて

Tags: letsencrypt

`renew` コマンドでサーバ証明書を更新しようとしましたが、下記エラーで失敗しました。

```
WARNING:certbot.renewal:Renewal configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/xxx/domain.conf produced an unexpected error: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'manual_test_mode'. Skipping.
```

記載のあるconfファイルには `manual_test_mode = False` が記載されています。

何を直せば解決するのでしょうか。

Comment: 可能なら設定ファイルの内容と実行したコマンドも質問文に追記してもらうと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/3477

これと似た症状ですね。

certbot やプラグインを再インストールしてみると解決するかもしれません。